# Как создать объект, если конструктор приватный?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу понять, что здесь:

1. Требуется и нужно.
2. Где такое реально применяется?

Код:

```
class S
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_x;

    public function getX()
    {
        return $this->_x;
    }

    public function setX($x)
    {
        $this->_x = $x;
    }

    public static function getInstance() 
    {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$_instance;
     }

     private function __construct ()
     {
         $this->setX(1);
     }
}

$s1 = S::getInstance();
$s2 = S::getInstance();

/*
вставьте сюда Ваш код
создавать новые классы запрещено
*/

echo $s1->getX(); // должно вывести 1
echo $s2->getX(); // должно вывести 2
```

Comment: Ну что же вы, это же банальное комбо из Singleton + Registry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приведенный кусок кода, это реализация шаблона проектирования *Одиночка* ([Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)).

Шаблон *Одиночка* используется в случаях, когда в системе допускается использование какого-то объекта в единственном экземпляре. На практике это может быть полезно для реализации шаблона *Реестр* ([Registry](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/registry.html)). Классическая реализация на PHP подразумевает три момента:

1. Реализацию статического метода получения экземпляра *Одиночки*:

   ```
   $a = S::getInstance();
   ```
2. Приватный конструктор *Одиночки* для запрета прямого создания экземпляров:

   ```
   $a = new S(); // Ошибка
   ```
3. Приватный метод `__clone` для запрета [клонирования](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php) *Одиночек*:

   ```
   $a = S::getInstance();
   $b = clone $a; // Ошибка
   ```

В приведенной вами реализации третий пункт пропущен, как следствие, вы спокойно можете использовать клонирование:

```
$s1 = S::getInstance();
$s2 = S::getInstance();

$s2 = clone $s1;
$s2->setX(2);

echo $s1->getX(); // должно вывести 1
echo $s2->getX(); // должно вывести 2
```

**Для справки:**

Шаблон *Реестр* часто применяется, если в системе нужно централизованное хранилище какой-либо информации. Это могут быть как и некие настройки так и набор объектов-сервисов, которые используются повсеместно. Совсем не обязательно использовать связку *Одиночка* + *Реестр*. Можно передавать в экземпляр *Реестра* в явном виде в каждый класс, который в нем нуждается.

Answer (score 5):

Приватный конструктор плюс создающая функция нужны для контроля над созданием объекта. Это по существу паттерн «фабрика» или одна из его разновидностей. Используется, например, если вы хотите иметь несколько возможностей инициализации объекта.

В данном случае использование контроля над созданием используется с другой целью. Код реализует синглтон: функция `getInstance` заботится о том, чтобы было создан лишь один объект, и каждый запрос получал всё время этот же объект. Приватный конструктор не позволяет чужому коду создать свой экземпляр объекта.

Синглтон нужен, например, если у вас какой-то объект должен существовать лишь в единственном числе, (и создавать его заранее вы не хотите по каким-либо причинам).

---

Как заставить код вывести 2 для второй строчки, не знаю.

Comment: Вы забыли один маленький нюанс. Объекты можно не только создавать с помощью конструктора но и клонировать ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Не знал, это специфика PHP, вероятно?

Comment: Хм. Не думал, что это PHP специфичная фича, но да, в PHP можно клонировать объекты. Вроде даже в C# был интерфейс `IClonable`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev А разве для клонирования не используется в PHP `clone` ? а в объекте при клонировании есть метод `__clone()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в PHP `__clone` это магический метод определяющий логику клонирования. А для клонирования используется `$b = clone $a`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Это да, но синглтон его может и не имплементировать. То есть, _должен_ не имплементировать.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Значит, надо ещё запретить клонирование. Например, бросать в `__clone` исключение, или возвращать тот же объект.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я так и написал))) собссн конструктор тут вроде как и не причем получается, как вы описали в начале

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, смотрите мой ответ

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ответ верный. Наверное я просто неправильно прочитал изначально. Мне показалось, что вы говорите, что с помощью конструктора можно еще и клонировать..

Comment: Понял. Здесь нужно клонировать объект.

Comment: @manking: Именно так! Но мне кажется, ответ Dmitriy Simushev больше заслуживает быть принятым.